# Does my Galaxy S6 have an unlocked bootloader?

Tags: root-access, custom-roms, bootloader, bootloader-lock

I want to install the Resurrection Remix custom ROM on my SM-G920I (Australian Version). Before I start doing anything, I need to make sure that the bootloader is unlocked, so I don't brick my phone.

To find out the state of my bootloader, I tried doing a few things that I read online. First, having a look at download mode, by holding home, power and volume down on startup. It instead goes to "Odin Mode" and lists these items.

```
ODIN MODE
PRODUCT NAME: SM-G920I
CURRENT BINARY: Samsung Official
SYSTEM STATUS: Official
REACTIVATION LOCK: OFF
SECURE DOWNLOAD: Enabled
KNOX WARRANTY VOID: 0 (0x0000)
RP SWREV: B:4 K:2 S:2
```

Do any of these items tell me about the bootloader?

I then tried using the ADB and fastboot method. Fastboot refused to work for me, saying no devices found. I later found out that Samsung devices do not have a fastboot mode at all.

Lastly, I tried just going to Developer Options and enabling "Allow OEM Unlock", but this feature was nowhere to be found on my device.

How am I able to check if my bootloader is unlocked, so I can root and flash a custom ROM on my device?

Answer (score 0):

Most if not all non-US-carrier Samsung devices come with unlocked/unlockable bootloader; those without the "OEM Unlock" switch are simply unlocked by default. Just proceed with flashing TWRP or whatever ops you need to do next.

Comment: How do I make sure it's unlocked? I don't really want to end up bricking my phone.

Comment: AFAIK there's no *concrete* way of checking bootloader status on Samsung devices, since they have no fastboot mode. Most if not all sources on the internet will tell you to determine from the model number, i.e. whether it's from those US carriers.